# to be down to something - meaning

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

Source: http://news.yahoo.com/shaky-start-ukraine-turns-eastern-offensive-around-224521910.html

> Analysts say the dramatic turnaround **is down to** a combination of growing professionalism and ruthlessness from Kiev's forces on the one hand and the shifting nature of the support that Russia is giving the rebels.

How do you understand that expression?

Comment: See "down to" in Oald under idioms - http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/down_1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This expression does not sound natural to my (American) ear.  Instead of:

> Analysts say the dramatic turnaround **is down to** a combination of growing professionalism and ruthlessness from Kiev's forces on the one hand and the shifting nature of the support that Russia is giving the rebels.

I would expect either:

> Analysts say the dramatic turnaround **is due to** a combination of growing professionalism and ruthlessness from Kiev's forces on the one hand and the shifting nature of the support that Russia is giving the rebels.

or

> Analysts **put** the dramatic turnaround **down to** a combination of growing professionalism and ruthlessness from Kiev's forces on the one hand and the shifting nature of the support that Russia is giving the rebels.

All three quotes mean the same thing.  In the last example, "<subject> put <phenomenon> down to <cause(s)>" means "<subject> attributed <phenomenon> to <cause(s)>".  My mental picture is of an observer (such as a desk guard or a journalist) who is responsible for logging activity "writing down" in their log an observed cause and an observed effect.  My mental picture leaves some doubt as to whether the observer is sure about the cause-and-effect relationship.

Note that none of these examples are using the slang phrase "<subject> is down with that", which is much more common.  The slang phrase currently means either "<subject> thinks that is OK" or "<subject> strongly likes that".  It used to mean "<subject> is unable to work, because they have that (illness)".